# Can ASP.NET and node js share same IP address and port

Tags: asp.net, node.js, networking, express, ip

I want that requests to http://example.com/home/index should be servered by my ASP.NET application but http://example.com/mobile/uploaddata should be servered by an express js application...

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have try to see if works ?

Comment: express js application says address already in use...

Comment: Of course, you try to start a second web server (on the same 80 port). You can not have 2 services on the same port.

Comment: Agreed, but if I host express js application on port 8080 and ASP.NET application on post 80, then all the request will go to the ASP.NET application. How can I route the requests for '/mobile/uploaddata' to express js application and other requests to ASP.NET

Comment: What about a redirect from your ASP.NET app on 80 to your node app on another port? For example example.com/mobile/uploaddata would be served by ASP.NET and the response would be a redirect to example.com:8080/mobile/uploaddata. You could also use a simple reverse proxy like nginx. It listens on 80 and proxies request to either ASP.NET or node on whatever alternate ports they are on.

Comment: Will the redirection or reverse proxy be able to handle the post requests?